# How to Order by a specific column name in my SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm on a work of a social network site, so I want to list the users based on logged in user location

My table sample table structure is (id, name, username, password, country, state)

### Id, name, username, password, country, state

1, rameez, rameezrami, password, india, kerala

2, rameez1, rameezrami, password, india, kerala

3, rameez2, rameezrami, password, country1, state1

4, rameez3, rameezrami, password, country2, state2

If logged in user is from kerala I want to list all kerala users first then all other state users from india, then from other country how can I do this?

Comment: How do you know what state the user is from is this in the table (that is you have the id of the user) or is the state passed to the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE (state='kerala' OR country='India' OR 1=1) ORDER BY state='kerala' DESC, country='India' DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to want to order by some non-standard way, you have to create a column with your criteria and use that in your `ORDER BY`

```
   SELECT id, name, username, password, country, state, 
           if(state = 'kerala', 0, if(country='india', 1,2)) as ord_col
   FROM your_table
   ORDER BY ord_col
```